# Prevent whitespace on classifaction attribute fileds in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have a string classification attribute field as shown in the image

[image]

I need to prevent whitespaces to be saved through the field which will be affected in my pdp page and facets.
Is there any way to achieve this in hybris?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could create a *PrepareInterceptor* for *ProductFeatureModel* that could just remove the whitespaces from selected attribute.
2. If the attribute has predefined set of possible values then you could consider defining them using ClassificationAttributeValue and this way preventing users from inserting invalid values